# Change currency label on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.8, currency

I need to change the currency label(symbol) on the last checkout page,
I need to change it from KR to DKK ( i'm from Denmark ) and only on the totals

I don't know anything about magento so please help

Answer (score 2):

I don't get your question. Do you want to change the currency symbol on the final step of the checkout process only? That doesn't really make any sense to me, or did you install a plugin that displays the wrong currency there?

The currency is a global setting in Magento, which you can change in the backend/admin. Go to System -> Configuration -> General -> Currency to alter these settings.

Comment: Yes i only want to change the currency symbol on the checout page in the totals section, because in denmark the credit card company (nets/ teller) requires this :-(

/aklausen Klausen